# AdMob Network Requests drops to 0 suddenly

Tags: android, admob

My App Admob Network Requests drops to 0 suddenly a month ago without any warning or error from google.

- ads are still showing in the app I've tested on 10 mobiles.
- crash rate is the same as before.
- user metrics are the same

so app is working ads are still showing no crash and users are using the app but network requests are dropped.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please display your gradle and manifest files? Is everything up to date?

Comment: What kind of app is it?

Comment: @sajad-abbasi Any updates on this?

Comment: @doctorram Unfortunately no

Comment: @sajadabbasi You need to make your app paid instead or use some network other than AdMob.